# facebox() error object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, facebox

I have an application that contains this code:

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="Javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[rel=facebox]').facebox();
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <a rel="facebox" href="WebForm1.aspx">Open Facebox Dialog with 0 opacity</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this one the facebox works very well,
Im applying the same principle in another application in which i render my anchor 
dynamically :

```
  link = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
  link.InnerText = Path.GetFileName(value);
  link.Attributes.Add("rel", "facebox");
  link.Attributes.Add("href", "WebForm1.aspx");
  panel.Controls.Add(link);<br/>
```

and ive got this code on my page

```
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebox.js"></script>
    <link href="css/facebox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="Javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[rel=facebox]').facebox();
        });
    </script>
```

In this one Im having an error on facebox(). Object doesnt support this property or method.Why m i getting this error although i do have the same code in another application
and it works perfectly there ?!?!
Thanks alot

Comment: I'm guessing that `$('a[rel=facebox]')` is returning nothing

Comment: by alert($('a[rel=facebox]')) i get an object  and not null, so i think it sees the anchor

Comment: in firebug, what does `$.facebox` return if you enter it in the console?

Comment: `js/facebox.js` file does not exist then, make sure its the right path

Comment: the file exists, and the path is correct coz when i write $(). i can see the function facebox() there

Comment: what is the exact line that firebug complains about?

Comment: am using IE and i dont know how to do debug it..m not used to it. but in my case m obligated to use IE

Comment: download firefox, and then install firebug from getfirebug.com, this will help you debug the issue... it doesn't sound like an IE only issue

Comment: I think i know what the problem is but i cant figure out how to fix it..my page extends from a class .cs in which i load my js files. so when im putting my facebox.js file either in my page or in the cs file.. it cant find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but when i put the script tage inside the body it worked

Answer (score 0):

And, is the path `js/facebox.js` exists inside the page location?

Remember that the link to the js file will be relative to the current page location since you are not providing ab absolute path to the file and probabliy you are using a page in a diferent location from the Master.Page of the site root .

Comment: Since you get undefined in firebug the most obvious problem is the files not loading. On Firebug, go to the Net tab and reload page and see if some request fails.

Comment: I think i know what the problem is but i cant figure out how to fix it..my page extends from a class .cs in which i load my js files. so when im putting my facebox.js file either in my page or in the cs file.. it cant find it